# Protractor wait for angular application to be stable

Tags: angular, protractor, ngrx

I have an issue when running e2e tests with Protractor. It seems the `whenStable` is being called too early (a fraction of a second early).

I load the data via guards, populate the store and then the containers receive this data via selectors which then pass the data down to the components.

My application is built with Angular 5 and ngrx 4.

Is there a way to successfully get `whenStable` to trigger at the right time without creating my own function for checking if an element is present?

Edited this post as it's no longer a remote baseUrl issue. I now have it happening locally.

I have a test application that seems to work as expected, but in my larger application, everything seems to happen a little too early.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understood the question correctly. But using browser.waitForAngular(); will wait for all angular components to load.

Comment: I should not need to add `browser.waitForAngular();`. I do use this when I want to wait after an action.

Comment: turns out there is some sort of race condition in my guard.